# UIView animation undoes a previous animation

Tags: animation, ios7, uikit

I have three **UIImageViews** (A, B, C) laid out in a **UIView**, side by side. Behind the first **UIImageView** (A), there is a simple **UIView** (which let us call X) with a green background. When a user taps one of the A, B, C image views, I move (and animate) the background view X, and make its center equal to the center of the view tapped. For example, if X was behind A initially, and B was tapped, then the following code would execute:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                 animations:^{ X.center = B.center } 
                 completion:nil];
```

which would move X behind B.

Now, my window also contains another view (let us call it V), that when tapped, it animates by calling

```
[UIView animateWithFramesWithDuration ... ]
```

However, when this animation finishes, the first animation is undone (X moves behind A always). Why does this happen ? What can I do to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23613137/255489), this is reproducible only in views created in a storyboard. Is auto layout enabled in the storyboard? If so, you should not be animating `center`, and I would expect the behavior you are seeing if you were. When you create the views programmatically, if you are not setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`, then your animations should work as expected when you animate `center`.

The correct way to animate views that are managed by auto layout constraints is to update the constraints to represent the new layout and then, in a `[UIView animateWith…]` block, call `-layoutIfNeeded` on the appropriate view.

Comment: Thank you. Auto-layout is indeed enabled, although I have not used any constraints in my views.

Comment: I believe there are implicit constraints set in the storyboard by Xcode for any views where you have not set constraints. Basically, with Auto Layout enabled in Xcode 5, views behave as though they had default autoresizing masks until you set your own constraints. Much better than Xcode 4’s insistence on always having valid constraints, which made them very difficult to work with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem exists only for **UIViews** that are created in a Storyboard. For **UIViews** that are created programmatically, the problem does not manifest.